# Best Way To Select Cell To Add To Different Table View

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have 2 views with tables.  Pressing the + button on one opens the other table up in a new view and you select the cell and it should then dismiss that view and add the data to a cell in the original view.

I got the 2nd table view all set up.  I have to make it so when you select the cell, it adds it to the favorite.  Or maybe even select multiple cells, then press the done button, then it adds to favorites.  Any ideas on how to go about this? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

addEvent method just for reference:

```
-(void)addEvent
{    
    Routine *routine = (Routine *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Routine" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    routine.name=entered;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) 
    {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", error);

    //[eventsArray addObject:routine];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

    NSInteger lastSection = [self.routineTableView numberOfSections] -1;


    [self.routineTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.routineTableView numberOfRowsInSection:lastSection]-1 inSection:lastSection] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
}
```

**EDIT 2**

This method is in view1, but needs to be displayed in view2, and the data is selected from view 4.

```
-(void)addExercise
{    
    Exercise *exercise = (Exercise *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Exercise" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    exercise.name=entered;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) 
    {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", error);

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

    NSInteger lastSection = [self.routineTableView numberOfSections] -1;

    [self.routineTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.routineTableView numberOfRowsInSection:lastSection]-1 inSection:lastSection] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
}
```

**EDIT 3:**

```
-(void)addExercise
{    
    if (managedObjectContext == nil) 
    { 
        managedObjectContext = [(CurlAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 
    }

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Exercise" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    [mutableFetchResults release];
    [request release];

    Exercise *exercise = (Exercise *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Exercise" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    exercise.name=@"Test";

    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) 
    {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", error);

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

    NSInteger lastSection = [self.tableView numberOfSections] -1;

    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:lastSection]-1 inSection:lastSection] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
    [tableView reloadData];
    [self viewDidLoad];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `didSelect` method of 2nd `tableView` you will need to update the `datasource` of first table and then either call reload when done button is pressed or use `insertRowsAtIndex` method.

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks, Ravin, that makes sense.  What is the best way to update the data source of the first table?  The first table is loaded using fetchresultscontroller.

Comment: It will depend on how you 2nd view comes and which is its viewController(in that case you can use delegation) to inform the other controller about update or have one reference of 1st controller in second so that you can access first's method. add few methods for data updatation. Another thing which is possible is that as you are using fetchResultsController so just update your core data with the selected data in controller two(using insert method for coredata as you are doing), changes might come once you call reload table.

Comment: The 2nd view is pushed onto the navigation stack and is a separate class.  I think I will need to go the core data route to do this.

Comment: yes, as you are using fetchresultscontroller it will be the right approach.

Comment: Thanks Ravin.  Do you think you could help with with how to add the selected cell to the core data model? I posted the addEvent method that I used in another view just for a place to start.

Comment: Faisal,does the direct call to that method create some problem?

Comment: well, that method adds to the routines's name property, this method should add to the routine's exercise property.  Do I have to add all the fetchedresults code to this viewcontroller to or can I just import the other one?

Comment: so create a method that do so in your firstViewController and call this from secondViewController using firstViewController's reference as you are using navigationController you can get its reference from naviation stack.

Comment: Ok, perfect ill do that.  Im going to search for how to do a reference, but if its only a line or two of code for reference can you post an example? thanks

Comment: int indexOfPreviousViewController = [self.navigationController viewControllers]-2; yourFirstViewControllerRef = [[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:indexOfPreviousViewController ]; or If you know correct index you can supply it directly.

Comment: Ravin I'm still having some trouble. Lets say the root controller is view1 (this is where the user created routines are listed).  Then view 2 is a tablesubview where the exercises for each routine is listed.  Right now all my fetchedresultscontroller code and methods are in view 1.  View 3 is the tableview that displays the data from which user can choose from and selected exercise needs to be displayed in view2.

Comment: I've added the method to add data to core data in question.

Comment: Faisal, It means we have 3 Views? 1st for Routine,2nd for Exercise, and 3rd from which user can select the item? are all of these views have different view controller? Does view2(Exercise) also uses fetchResults? try with putting that addExcercise method in 3rd viewController  because once data is updated no matter where it could reflect.

Comment: The 2nd viewController is the one I am working with in this question, so as of now it has no fetch results, this is one that the data selected from the 3rd vieww ill be added to.  THe 3rd view is populated from a .plist array.

Comment: does it updated cored data also? if so then call both the methods, addExcercise and add it to your 2nd view's datasource. I think now you can go for delegation.

Comment: Yes, the first addRoutine adds to Core Data, so If I make an addExercsie it should add to core data as well.  I'm not sure about delegation stuff I havne't really done anything with that before.

Comment: You can use notification also. But you should learn both methods.

Comment: Hey Ravin, so I got everything setup to where I click a cell in the modal table, it dismisses and adds a new cell to the routine's exercise table called "Test".  I just did this to make sure everything is in place.  How do i get it to result in the same string as the cell I clicked.  Because the didselectrow calls a method in the separate class with the actual list of cells is to be added.

Comment: Faisal "How do i get it to result in the same string as the cell I clicked." by this do you mean fetchResults (on 1stViewController)?

Comment: Umm, what I mean is how do I make it so a new cell is added and the text is the same as the cell I selected in the other table.

Comment: are you not updating the other tables datasource? add some method that could do this work and call it on that selection.

Comment: I just updated question with the addExercise method I am currently using that is being called.

Comment: and it will update the core data, But your 2nd view controller does not uses fetchresultsRequest and you want to update the value in 2nd viewcontroller's table?

Comment: actually both of them viewControllers use fetched results .  the only one that doesnt is the one that we select the row from, but i don't think that matters.

Comment: if you are calling -(void)addExercise method then you can pass selected value in it -(void)addExercise:(NSString *)newNameValue;, Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: hmm I guess that may work.  But how am I passing the string from the cells' text of the modal view, to a different viewcontroller that this addExercise method is in

Comment: what you can do is... have an instance variable (as property which you can set from anywhere) of 2ndViewController in your modal controller(3rdController) and set that with self when you create the object of third while presenting it.

Comment: hmm, ok ill try that thanks, can you please look at this question? thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713225/why-is-my-uipickerview-crashing

Comment: Hey Ravin, are you still there? I'm still having trouble getting the title from the selected row to be added to the title of the new cell added.