# Why Is My UIPickerView Crashing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am getting the following error when I load the view with my UIPickerView:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5906000'

Here is all my code related to the picker:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad:
NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:700];
    for ( int i = 1 ; i <= 100 ; i ++ )
        [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
    weightArray = array;
    //[array release];

 #pragma mark - Weight Picker 
    - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView 
    {
        return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component 
    {
        return [weightArray count];
    }

    - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component 
    {
        return [weightArray objectAtIndex:row];
    }

    - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component 
    {

       // NSLog(@"Selected Color: %@. Index of selected color: %i", [weightArray objectAtIndex:row], row);
    }
```

**Update**

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    if (thePickerView.tag==1)
    {
        //float weight = [[pickerArray objectAtIndex:row] intValue];
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 37)];
        float weight = [[pickerArray objectAtIndex:row] floatValue];
        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f lb", weight];
        //label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f lb", weight];
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:30];
        [label autorelease];
        return label;
    }

    else
    {
        int reps = [[pickerArray objectAtIndex:row] intValue];
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 37)];
        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d reps", reps];
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:30];
        [label autorelease];
        return label;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Faisal, Can you check log for [weightArray objectAtIndex:row];?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Faisal,
I think problem lies

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component 
    {
        return [weightArray objectAtIndex:row];
    }
```

in above method... weightArray is array of NSNumber. and you are treating it as string you should rather try following

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component 
    {
        int weight = [[weightArray objectAtIndex:row] intValue];
        NSString *pickerTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",weight];
        return pickerTitle;
    }
```

**Regarding Picker methods**

```
 #pragma mark - Weight Picker 
    - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView 
    {
       use like this...
       if(thePickerView.tag==1)
       {
        return 1;
       }
      else if(thePickerView.tag==2)
       {
        return 2; //just for example...
       }
      else 
        return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component 
    {
        return [weightArray count];
    }

    - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component 
    {
        if(thePickerView.tag==1)
        {
          return [weightArray objectAtIndex:row];
        }
         else if(thePickerView.tag==1)
        {
          return ;//your other value and so on.....
        }
    }
```

Thanks,

Comment: thanks Ravin, i got error `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CALayer intValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4d28e70'
*** Call stack at first throw:` at the int weight = .... line

Comment: faisal, it means elements of weightArray is going out of scope. I want to ask you why dont you add integers that you are adding to array, directly in weightArray, because I feel that array is going out of scope to which weightArray points. Are you releasing array? if so then dont release it, add objects directly in weight array .

Comment: I took out [array release]; and it works fine now.  Do I ever release this array?

Comment: Or how can I edit the code so it adds directly to weightArray and there is no array?

Comment: are you changing weightArray somewhere else or is it coming from somewhere else(if you are probably setting it from outside). If not than rather than intializing array , use weightArray and do same stuff, release it in dealloc. no need to use array.

Comment: ya i don't need to use array, ill just use weightArray, it is not being edited anywhere else.

Comment: One last question Ravin, this particular class has 2 views, each their own UIPicker, how can I set the data source methods for each picker? Right now it is setting the one picker, how do I tell the other methods to set the other picker?

Comment: In all pickerView delegate methods you are getting pickerView, so you just set different tag of both the pickerView and check the tag and do as per your need.

Comment: hmm do you mean for example this method: `- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView`, the tag would be thePickerView?  So just change that?

Comment: I mean when you show two different pickerView, they should set their tag after you intialize it and the common method you can use for both the pickerView's discreminating both on the basis of tag. in that method you will have to use and check thePickerView.tag==1 then do this  or if thePickerView.tag==2 do other stuff.

Comment: I'm not sure how this .tag == 1 stuff works.  Is this atuomaticaly implemeteD?

Comment: yes it is property of all UIViews, we mostly use it to discremenate between one another, when situation like this, as you are having arises, suppose i have two different alerts and want different action on its button click so how will i differentiate between which alert which button in delegate, so I will use tag to recognize which alert. Try once, what you have to do when you show pickerview set different tag's for both the picker's and then check it in delegate do some nslog you will see whether its working or not.

Comment: Ok, so I have like 4 views in this nib, and 2 of the views have a uipickerview, how can i find out which tag is 1, 2 etc.

Comment: we have to set it, as you are adding it through xib, you have to select a pickerView and in its attributes you have will see tag property, you can set it 1 or 100 for one view and some different value for another. also, you can set it programmatically using, picker1.tag =1; picker2.tag=2.

Comment: Ok perfect, I have made one picker tag 1, other picker tag 2, now how can I continue with the methods (i'm just using the ones as in hte question)? thanks.

Comment: I updated question with the code I am using but getting error at if statement thePickerView.tag =1

Comment: it is not finding thePickerview (use of undeclared identiifer), what other term would it be under?

Comment: hey in argument its pickerView..... use pickerView not thePickerView. we are mentioning  the UIPickerView comming in argument. please make changes as per arguments name.

Answer (score 0):

It means that you are trying to comapre values with a nonexisting method. In other words NSCFNumber doeas not have a method isEqualToString implementation. For number use this method:

```
if(someNumber == [someString intValue]){

}
```

Comment: Thanks Cyprian. How can I incorporate that into my code above?  Im assuming it would go where the array init method is.

Comment: Ok actually looking closer at your code I think the problem is this. You put your values for the UIPicker as NSNumber and store them in the array called weightArray. But to use those numbers in a UIPicker they need to be NSStrings so do this and it should work: `[array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i]];` insert this in the for loop instead of your current code.

Comment: Thanks Cyprrian, i tried that but get the same error.  I posted the updated code in question